# How to get file path of copied file in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-10, clipboard

This is for files which I copy anywhere in explorer either from right click context menu or Ctrl+C.

I looked at [System.Windows.Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=net-5.0) but there doesn't seem to be a method to get any information about a file which was copied.

Any help in appreciated.

Comment: [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents).

Answer (score 2):

this work for you

Clipboard is inside System.Windows.Forms, use this way:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsFileDropList())
{
    var filesArray = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
    //now you have a array of file address 
}
else if(Clipboard.ContainsText())
{
    var fileName = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use This

```
Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
```

Comment: This is what the other answer said many hours before this one.

Comment: This is what the other answer said many hours before this one.